# Dispatch After Download is Finished in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am downloading files in swift, and the download session is triggered by a button on each table view cell. However, I do not want the next download (if someone presses the download button on another cell) to happen until after the previous one is finished.

Is there a way that I can use something like dispatch_after to accomplish this?

Here is my code where the downloading occur, if it helps at all.

```
//FUNCTION TO DOWNLOAD THE PDF
//PASS THE ONLINE PDF URL AS NSURL
//ASYNC REQUEST
let defaultSession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
var dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask?
var temp_name = String()
var temp_index = Int()
var temp_indexPath = NSIndexPath()

lazy var downloadsSession: NSURLSession = {

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    return session
}()
func getUrl(name: String) -> NSURL?{
    let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as NSURL!
    return documentsUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(name)
}

func getIndex() -> Int?{
    return temp_index
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {

    if let originalURL = downloadTask.originalRequest?.URL?.absoluteString,
        destinationURL =  getUrl(temp_name){

        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        do {
            try fileManager.removeItemAtURL(destinationURL)
        } catch {
            // Non-fatal: file probably doesn't exist
        }
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItemAtURL(location, toURL: destinationURL)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not copy file to disk: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }


    if let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.URL?.absoluteString {
        activeDownloads[url] = nil

        if let trackIndex = getIndex() {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                defaults.setBool(false, forKey: self.temp_name + "_downloading")


                self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: trackIndex, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .None)
            })
        }
    }


}


func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    if let downloadUrl = downloadTask.originalRequest?.URL?.absoluteString,
        download = activeDownloads[downloadUrl] {
        download.progress = Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        if let trackIndex = getIndex(), let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: trackIndex, inSection: 0)) as? MainTableViewCell {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                cell.progress.progress = download.progress
                if(download.progress < 1.0){
                    cell.progress.hidden = false
                }
                else{
                   cell.progress.hidden = true
                }
            })
        }

    }

}

// Action triggered by UIButton (in this case the download button)
//Access tag, which is the IndexPath.row, using sender.tag
@IBAction func downloadFile(sender: UIButton){
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell
    cell.downloadButton.hidden = true
    cell.progress.progress = 0
    cell.progress.hidden = false



    let isAvailable = true
    let key = names[sender.tag] + "_offline"
    defaults.setValue(isAvailable, forKey: key)
    let name = (names[sender.tag])
    let fileName = name + ".pdf"
    let attachment = attachments[sender.tag]
    temp_name = fileName
    temp_index = sender.tag
    temp_indexPath = indexPath
    let destinationURL =  getUrl(temp_name)!
    defaults.setValue(destinationURL.path!, forKey: name + "_path")
    defaults.synchronize()
    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: name + "_downloading")
    let urlString = attachment
    let url =  NSURL(string: urlString)

    let download = PDFDownload(url: urlString)

    download.downloadTask = downloadsSession.downloadTaskWithURL(url!)
    download.downloadTask!.resume()
    download.isDownloading = true

    activeDownloads[download.url] = download

}
```

There is a boolean that stores whether or not a download session is occurring, so maybe there is a way that I can use that? Wait until the boolean is false to execute my code?

Comment: you can disable the button after it is clicked the first time and re-enable it in the completion handler for your network call

Comment: Let me clarify- they are buttons on each table view cell, and I still want the other ones to work but just to wait until starting downloading

Comment: ah, one thing you could do then is to use a serial dispatch_queue, or you could wrap it in an NSOperation and use a serial NSOperation queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Deepak kumar answer is correct,But adding dependency for each operation is not good idea.
you can do it in a simpler way. only 3 steps required.

1. create NSOperationQueue object.
2. then set the property maxConcurrentOpeations to 1.
3. then add operations to queue , it will perform the operations one by one.

Comment: Awesome- that makes more sense

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSOperationQueue to accomplish this. Create one operationqueue and one NSOperation object to store previous operation which was added to operation queue before the current operation. on every click on tableviewcell's button create new NSOperation instance and before adding it to  operationqueue do the followings.

1- check if tempoperation is nil. then assign current operation to it and then add to operation queue.
2.  else add dependency on tempoperation first then assign current operation to it and then add to operation queue.

This way each task will start after the completion of previous task. Hope this will help you. :)